# Find the value of $4\cos 6\cos 42 \cos 60 \cos 66 \cos 78$ All angles in degrees

Tags: trigonometry

I have absolutely no idea on how to go about this, except that cos 60 =1/2 :)

The usual way of multiplying by a sine doesn’t work here, and I feel very dumb for not being able to solve it. However, help would be appreciated.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455070/proving-a-fact-tan6-circ-tan42-circ-tan12-circ-tan24-cir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\begin{align}P 
&= 4\cos6°\cos42°\cos60°\cos66°\cos78° \cr  
&= {1\over2}(2\cos6° \cos66°)(2\cos42° \cos78°) \cr
&= {1\over2}(\cos72° + \cos60°)(\cos120° + \cos36°)\cr
&= {1\over8}(2\cos72° + 1)(-1 + 2\cos36°)
\end{align}$

From [Golden triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_triangle_(mathematics)), $\quad\quad2\cos36° = \phi = \large{1+\sqrt5 \over 2}$

From [Golden ratio identity,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio) $\phi^2 = \phi+1$

$2\cos72°+1 = 2(2\cos^2 36°-1) + 1 = \phi^2-1 = \phi$

$$P = {\phi(\phi-1) \over 8} = {\phi^2-\phi \over 8} = {1\over8}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint :-

**Use- $\cos(a)\cos(60+a)\cos(60-a)=\frac14\cos3a$**

Comment: I was not aware of that.

Comment: You must come across that when you read further on trignometric function on multiples and submultiples of angle

Comment: Should i add steps also if you require

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1145406/prove-that-cos-x-cdot-cosx-60-circ-cdot-cosx60-circ-frac14

Answer (score 0):

Like

1. [A trigonometric equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/557360/a-trigonometric-equation)
2. [Evaluate $\tan^{2}(20^{\circ}) + \tan^{2}(40^{\circ}) + \tan^{2}(80^{\circ})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175736/evaluate-tan220-circ-tan240-circ-tan280-circ)
3. [Proving a fact: $\tan(6^{\circ}) \tan(42^{\circ})= \tan(12^{\circ})\tan(24^{\circ})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455070/proving-a-fact-tan6-circ-tan42-circ-tan12-circ-tan24-cir)
4. [Prove that $\tan70^\circ - \tan50^\circ + \tan10^\circ = \sqrt{3}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/770391/prove-that-tan70-circ-tan50-circ-tan10-circ-sqrt3)

Observe that $$\cos5x=\cos30^\circ$$ for $x=6^\circ,78^\circ,150^\circ,222^\circ=(180+42)^\circ,294^\circ=(360-66)^\circ$

Now $\cos5x+\cos x=2\cos3x\cos2x=2(4\cos^3x-3\cos x)(2\cos^2x-1)$

$\cos5x=16\cos^5x-(12+8)\cos^3x+(6-1)\cos x$

So, if $\cos5x=\cos5A,5x=360^\circ n\pm5A$ where $n$ is any integer

$x=72^\circ n+ A$ where  $n=0,1,2,3,4$

So, the roots of  $$16c^5-20c^3+5c-\cos5A=0$$  are $\cos(72^\circ n+ A)$ where  $n=0,1,2,3,4$

$$\implies\prod_{n=0}^4\cos(72^\circ n+ A)=\dfrac{\cos5A}{16}$$

Can you complete from here?

**See also** :

[Prove that $\tan55^\circ\cdot\tan65^\circ\cdot\tan75^\circ=\tan85^\circ$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/783878/prove-that-tan55-circ-cdot-tan65-circ-cdot-tan75-circ-tan85-circ)

[Trigonometric Equation $\sin x=\tan\frac{\pi}{15}\tan\frac{4\pi}{15}\tan\frac{3\pi}{10}\tan\frac{6\pi}{15}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/503575/trigonometric-equation-sin-x-tan-frac-pi15-tan-frac4-pi15-tan-frac3)