# Evaluate sum of tangents $\tan^4{10°}+\tan^4{50°}+\tan^4{70°}$

Tags: trigonometry

How to evaluate $$\tan^4{10°}+\tan^4{50°}+\tan^4{70°} = ?$$

It should equals 59.

But I don't know how?
I also think that we should use power-reduction formulas.

Comment: Please show your effort..... Then we will happy to help...:-)

Comment: Does this https://math.stackexchange.com/a/770557/876009 help you Liza?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175736/evaluate-tan220-circ-tan240-circ-tan280-circ

Comment: Once a question has received an answer which is either accepted or with a positive score, it is no longer within the poster's power to remove the question. Therefore, please don't change it to invalidate other people's work.

Comment: Please do *not* make question edits which invalidate existing (valid) answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the triple-angle identity
$$\tan 3x = \frac{3\tan x-\tan^3x}{1-3\tan^2x}$$
$\tan 10^\circ$, $-\tan50^\circ$ and $\tan 70^\circ$ are the three roots of
$$ \sqrt3 (3t- t^3)=1-3t^2$$

Square to get $3t^6+33t^2 = 27t^4+1$,
and square again to get the cubic equation
$$9t^{12} -531t^8 +1035t^4-1=0$$
in $t^4$, with roots $\tan^410^\circ$, $\tan^450^\circ$ and $\tan^470^\circ$ . Thus
$$\tan^4{10°}+\tan^4{50°}+\tan^4{70°} =\frac{531}9=59$$

Comment: Thank you very much. It is interesting answer, but I can't understand how did you got the last equation from (9t^12−531t^8+1035t^4−1=0) this

Comment: @Liza - I used the Vieta’s formula for the sum of roots $\tan^4\theta$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas

Comment: Ingenuous! +1!!!!!!