# Proving $\cot 20^\circ - \cot 40^\circ + \cot 80^\circ = \sqrt{3}$

Tags: trigonometry, contest-math, problem-solving

> Prove that:
> $$\cot 20^\circ - \cot 40^\circ + \cot 80^\circ = \sqrt{3}$$

What I have learnt in trigonometry so far: Trigonometric ratios and their graphs, formulas of ratios for compound angles, sum and product formulas of ratios (eg. $2 \sin A \cos B = \sin (A+B) + \sin (A-B)$ ).

An answer using the things I have learnt would be appreciated. I tried this multiple times by trying to simplify to tan and then using the expression for $\tan (A+B)$, but it didn't work out.

EDIT: My attempt in detail:

$$\cot 20^\circ - \cot 40^\circ + \cot 80^\circ = [(\tan 20^\circ + \tan 80^\circ) / \tan 20^\circ \tan 80^\circ ] - 1 / \tan 40^\circ$$

After this I further tried to get it in some form of ratio with which I could get angles like $ 30^\circ$ or $ 60^\circ $, but I was unable to do it. There were two other proofs prior to this one, which seemed to use the same strategy.

Source: *Challenge and Thrill of Pre-College Mathematics*

Comment: Can you please show what you tried?

Comment: Can you use complex numbers?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/770391/prove-that-tan70-circ-tan50-circ-tan10-circ-sqrt3

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455070/proving-a-fact-tan6-circ-tan42-circ-tan12-circ-tan24-cir

Comment: @MathLover I have edited my post to include the basics of what I tried, all further attempts stemmed from it.

Comment: @Ihf I have not learnt complex numbers till now, but a proof is always welcome. Thanks. I'm seeing the other post you have linked, please wait while I try to figure out a relation.

Comment: labbhattacharjee's linked answer has the correct strategy. Note that $\cot 40^\circ = -\cot 140^\circ$

Comment: @Ihf thank you so much, the link immediately helped me find out a solution myself. I'll be posting it.

Comment: @Iab bhattacharjee thanks you to as well, in fact, the problem posted there turned out to be the very next question! So the correct strategy, I would assume, is these little additional identities one can prove, then apply them to such problems.

Comment: Small correction: in your example formula for compound angles, please change the left hand side to $2 \sin A \cos B$ .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a solution using the formula for the sum of cosines of compound angles:
$$\cos{(A+B)} \; + \; \cos{(A-B)}=2\cos{A}\cos{B}$$

An intuitive point here is that we see double angles (20, 40 ,80) so we can use formulae for $\sin{2A}$ and $\cos{2A}$. The trick is to work with two terms at a time, as marked with colors below. We also note that $\sin{(90-A)}=\cos{A}$ .

Alright, let's start with the two leftmost terms:
$$
\begin{align}
&\quad \; \color{blue}{\cot20 \; - \; \cot40} \; + \cot80 \\[2ex]
&= \color{blue}{\frac{\cos20}{\sin20} \; - \; \frac{\cos40}{\sin40}} \; + \; \frac{\cos80}{\sin80} \tag1 \\[2ex]
&= \color{blue}{\frac{\cos20}{\sin20} \; - \; \frac{2\cos^{2}20-1}{2\sin20\cos20}} \; + \; \frac{\cos80}{\sin80} \tag2 \\[2ex]
&= \color{blue}{\frac{1}{\sin40}} \; + \; \frac{\cos80}{2\sin40\cos40} \tag3 \\[2ex]
&= \frac{2\cos40 \; + \; \cos80}{2\sin40\cos40} \tag4 \\[2ex]
&= \frac{\cos40 \; + \; \color{green}{\cos40 \; + \; \cos80}}{\sin80} \tag5 \\[2ex]
&= \frac{\cos40 \; + \; \color{green}{2\cos60\cos20}}{\sin80} \tag6 \\[2ex]
&= \frac{\cos40 \; + \; \color{green}{\cos20}}{\cos10} \tag7 \\[2ex]
&= \frac{2\cos30\cos10}{\cos10} \tag8 \\[2ex]
&= 2\cos30 = \sqrt3 \tag9 \\[2ex]
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thanks for the solution!

Comment: You are welcome!